# Is there a way to communicate with a particular player or particular clan?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I accidentally rejected someone entry from the clan. I felt really bad about it because I recognized his name, and he explained that he comes on leaves the clan frequently for trophy reasons. Is there anyway I can send an invite now that he's in another clan?

In clash of the clans can you communicate with anyone outside of your clan? I know there's the global chat, but it's not a good chance someone will see a message addressed to them?

Aside from your own clan, can you ever message another clan, for example in war?

Comment: As long as you can find the user, you can click 'Invite' to invite them to your clan. As for messaging other clans, you can't.

Comment: @angussidney I thought if they already have a clan you can't invite them? How do you do this?

Comment: No, you cannot even invite a user if they are already in a clan. Messaging in clash of clans is restricted a lot; you can only message players in your clan through clan chat that is visibly to clan members only, and global (where you cannot be sure that you are in the same 'global' each time you log in, yes there are many 'globals' and you cannot pick one).

Answer (score 2):

Jerry is correct for what he mentioned in the comments.

## Is there anyway I can send an invite now that he's in another clan?

**Currently, no.**  He has to be not in any clan first.  You can try going to the clan he is in (pass clan leader first to someone you trust if needed), and messaging him in the clan chat to let him try again.

## In clash of the clans can you communicate with anyone outside of your clan?

You can only chat 3 ways in Clash of clans:

1. Clan chat
2. Global Chat
3. Send a clan message (cannot directly reply through this though)

## Aside from your own clan, can you ever message another clan, for example in war?

**Currently, no.**

If you are looking to chat directly to someone, your best bet is to utilize a third party application (like KIK, etc).

Comment: I suggested kik but they were like "I don't want to have to switch between apps"

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question but I will just give an update. After the Oct 2016 update, a player in game can add another player in the game as a *Friend* (For that you send a *friend request* and then if the other person *accepts* then you become friends. If two players are *friends*, they can invite each other to their clans even if the other person is already in a clan (of course only if they have the privilege to *invite* someone in clan). Also, you can search a person with his *tag* or *id* (a number in his/her profile). But you still cannot chat or message each other except if you both are in same clan or in same global chat.

*Happy Clashing!*

Answer (score 0):

You can now invite people while in a clan. However, you have to add them to your friends list. After you add them as a friend you go to social and scroll down to where they are on the list and click on them and invite will pop up.